# This technique for functional programming, and testing functional programming

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, functional-programming

I've been playing around with functional programming and testing with jest recently.

An issue I've run into, is that it's hard to mock ES6 module exports directly. [See this Stack Overflow question for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736766/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-for-testing-mocking-functions-within-a-module-in-20)

The solution I've come up with is to inject the dependency functions into the function that is calling it, via `.bind`.

Here's an example:

```
import axios from "axios";
const BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
const URI_USERS = 'users/';

/**
* These are the implementation of our functions, which take functions as arguments.  
*/

export const _fetchUsers = async function (_makeApiCall, _URI_USERS) {
    return _makeApiCall(_URI_USERS);
}


export const _fetchUser = async function (_makeApiCall, _URI_USERS, id) {
    return _makeApiCall(_URI_USERS + id);
}


export const _fetchUserStrings = async function (_fetchUser, _parseUser, ...ids) {
    const users = await Promise.all(ids.map(id => _fetchUser(id)));
    return users.map(user => _parseUser(user));
}
export const _makeApiCall = async function (uri) {
    try {
        const response = await axios(BASE_URL + uri);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err.message);
    }
}

export function _parseUser(user) {
    return `${user.name}:${user.username}`;
}



/**
 * Real exports
 */
export const makeApiCall = _makeApiCall;
export const parseUser = _parseUser;

export const fetchUsers = _fetchUsers.bind(null, _makeApiCall, URI_USERS);
export const fetchUser = _fetchUser.bind(null, _makeApiCall, URI_USERS);
export const fetchUserStrings = _fetchUserStrings.bind(null, _fetchUser, _parseUser);
```

And a test:

```
/**
 * Our most complicated test
 *  
 */

describe("_fetchUserStrings", () => {

    describe("happy flow", () => {

        const fetchUserMock = jest.fn((i) => Promise.resolve({
            username: "foo",
            name: "bar"
        }));
        const parseUserMock = jest.fn(user => "string");
        const fetchUserStrings = _fetchUserStrings.bind(null, fetchUserMock, parseUserMock);

        it("returns an array of three strings", async () => {

            expect.assertions(3);
            const result = await fetchUserStrings(1, 2, 3);

            // I'm being a bit lazy here, you could be checking that 
            // The strings are actually there etc, but whatevs. 

            expect(fetchUserMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
            expect(parseUserMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
            expect(result).toHaveLength(3);
        })

    });
});
```

My question is - is this a super clean way of writing functional JavaScript, or is this overkill that is easily solved another way?

If you're interested, there are more examples [here](https://github.com/dwjohnston/testing_with_jest).

Answer (score 1):

> or is this overkill that is easily solved another way?

`_fetchUser` and `_fetchUsers` appear to be the same function; save for the `id` parameter.

If interpret the question correctly, `_fetchUser` can be substituted for `_fetchUsers` (which can be removed entirely) by utilizing default parameters instead of `.bind()`.

For example

```
async function _makeApiCall (uri) {
  try {
    const response = await Promise.resolve(uri);
    return response;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  }
}

async function _fetchUsers({makeApiCall = _makeApiCall, _URI_USERS = 'abc', id = ''} = {}) {
  return await makeApiCall(_URI_USERS + id);
}

export default _fetchUsers;
```

---

```
<script type="module">
  import _fetchUsers from './script.js'; 
  (async() => {
    console.log(await _fetchUsers() // 'abc'
               , await _fetchUsers({id:'def'}) // 'abcdef'
               );
  })();
</script>
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MM2wzPWdcfMbXIz4AVbm?p=preview)

Comment: Re: deault parameters - this  makes it difficult/impsible to use a rest operator (for passing in an array of arguments) - see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752586/dependency-injection-rest-and-default-function-parameters-for-the-same-function, also - having the functions as parameters means they'll show up on the IDE and generally muddy it up.

Comment: Rest element and rest parameter are not an operators [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread syntax at MDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/) Concerning using both rest parameters and default parameters, are you trying to do something like [arrow functions: destructuring arguments and grabbing them as a whole at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47117312/2801559) or [Can we set persistent default parameters which remain set until explicitly changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43466657/2801559)? How is an IDE related to the question?

Comment: Alright - there's some fantastic resources there, thanks.